# Windows 8.1 App - don't bind to object when "clearing" value in a control

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

We have a controls that contains family member information (e.g. textbox for first name, last name, address, phone, etc).

This is done like the following bound to the FamilyMember object:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox" Text="{Binding FamilyMember.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="363" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

We have a button to create a new family member.  It's purpose is to blank out the fields.

In the scenario where we click on a family member it shows the values in the textboxes.  Now click on "create new" button and it should blank out the fields.

The problem i'm encountering is because the data is still bound to the previous family member ... the "blanking" out of the control values will also affect the previously selected family member object.

Question: Would I need to "unbind" the control and then do the reset on the fields?  I thought there was a way to do that in XAML but it doesn't seem like it is possible in Windows 8.1 apps.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it would be better to have a contained usercontrol that acts as a sub form for FamilyMember, with the lifetime of an individual add, sort of like if you took the user to a separate create member page. Wiping fields and changing bindings doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

@Nathan Cooper.  you're right. that's what I thought and I did something a bit different before coming back here to see if anyone had any ideas.

Basically there is a dropdown of family members.  I added a blank family member object into the dropdown.  So when the "new" family member button was pressed it would select the blank family member object.  So no wiping or anything that was out in left field when I first looked at this was done.

Thanks to all for taking a look and for your help.